# How to get last cell index in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a line chart for some data

```
Sub FinalTest()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A2:D352")
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=sheet1!$C$1"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=sheet1!$D$1"
    ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "TEST"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
    With ActiveChart.Parent
         .Height = 325 ' resize
         .Width = 3000  ' resize
         .Top = 100    ' reposition
         .Left = 350   ' reposition
    End With        
End Sub
```

My last cell is D352 and this index varies for different sheets. How can I change the code so that it works dynamically by taking the last used cell index?

Comment: If your data are in a contiguous block you can use `currentregion`.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that the last index is given by the last not empty cell in column A

Change:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A2:D352")
```

to:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this.

```
Sub FindingLastRow()

'PURPOSE: Different ways to find the last row number of a range
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastRow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

'Using Table Range
  LastRow = sht.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

'Using Named Range
  LastRow = sht.Range("MyNamedRange").Rows.Count

'Ctrl + Shift + Down (Range should be first cell in data set)
  LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

End Sub
```

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba